# variables defined in linker script not coming through in c++ startup file

Tags: c++, linker, startup, ld

I have the following linker script (left out irrelevant parts)

```
MEMORY
{
  PROGRAM_FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0x40000 
  SRAM_DTC (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x10000 
  SRAM_ITC (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x0, LENGTH = 0x10000
  SRAM_OC (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20200000, LENGTH = 0x20000 
}

ENTRY(ResetISR)

SECTIONS
{
     /* Image Vector Table and Boot Data for booting from external flash */
.boot_hdr : ALIGN(4)
{
    FILL(0xff)
    __boot_hdr_start__ = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
    KEEP(*(.boot_hdr.conf))
    . = 0x1000 ;
    KEEP(*(.boot_hdr.ivt))
    . = 0x1020 ;
    KEEP(*(.boot_hdr.boot_data))
    . = 0x1030 ;
    KEEP(*(.boot_hdr.dcd_data))
    __boot_hdr_end__ = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
    . = 0x2000 ;
} >PROGRAM_FLASH

.vector : ALIGN(4)
{
    FILL(0xff)
    __vector_table_flash_start__ = . ;
    __vector_table_dtc_start__ = LOADADDR(.vector) ;
    
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
    
    . = ALIGN(4) ;
    
    __vector_table_size__ = . ;
     
} >PROGRAM_FLASH
```

So relevant takeaways:

- flash memory starts at 0x600000000
- some XIP boot bytes are written to dedicated locations beginning of flash, followed by "my own stuff".
- I put vector tables at 0x60002000 (or better put, nxp sdk expects some xip bytes and jumps to 0x60002000 where I can put my own stuff).
- I am creating some variables with the current location so that I can use them in my startup script
- When I look at the disassembled code, i can clearly see that my vector tables described 0x45 words, so with above linker script I would expect that my `__vector_table_size__` at least would be 0x45

In my startup .cpp I added some `extern`s so that I can read the memory info created by the linker.

```
extern unsigned int __vector_table_flash_start__;
extern unsigned int __vector_table_dtc_start__;
extern unsigned int __vector_table_size__;
    
/* some temp vars so that my assignments don't get optimized out */
volatile unsigned int i;
volatile unsigned int ii;
volatile unsigned int iii;

__attribute__ ((naked, section(".after_vectors.reset")))
void ResetISR(void) {
    // Disable interrupts
    __asm volatile ("cpsid i");
    __asm volatile ("MSR MSP, %0" : : "r" (&_vStackTop) : );
    //__asm volatile ("LDR r9, = __global_offset_table_flash_start__");
    
    i = __vector_table_flash_start__;
    ii = __vector_table_dtc_start__;
    iii = __vector_table_size__;
}
```

Again, nothing interesting, just some code to make sure nothing is optimized out, and that I can see the actual values of the variables in the debugger.

When we know that my flash starts at `0x60000000` and that my `.vector` section has an offset of `0x2000`

| Variable | Expected | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **vector_table_flash_start** | 0x6002000 | 0x20010000 |
| **vector_table_dtc_start** | 0x6002000 | 0x20010000 |
| **vector_table_size** | 0x45 | 0xffffffff |

What I am doing wrong here??

For reference, the relevant section of disassemble (`arm-none-eabi-objdump --disassemble-all eclipse/MIMXRT1024_Project/Debug/MIMXRT1024_Project.axf > disassemble_pic`)

[image]

Comment: C++ doesn't have linker scripts. And names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__vector_table_flash_start__`, etc.) are reserved for use by the implementation .

Comment: Probably some name mangling problems. Try `extern "c" unsigned int __vector_table_flash_start__;`

Comment: @user253751 thank you... Learned something today....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the **address** of the linker script variables, not their value. The address is what the linker script sets. The value is what happens to be at that address - presumably the first vector in the vector table.